# Drawline apaga linhas anteriores

Tags: java

Como faço para desenhar mais de uma linha com o drawline? Ele sempre apaga o anterior ao desenhar uma nova, mas quero manter. O código é o seguinte

```
public class DrawLines extends JPanel{
    private final int[] origemXY = new int[2];
    private final int[] destinoXY = new int[2];
    Graphics2D g2;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        drawLinha(g);        
    }

    public void drawLinha(Graphics g){
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2)); 
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawLine(origemXY[0], origemXY[1], destinoXY[0], destinoXY[1]);        
    }

    public void drawLinha(int origemXY[], int destinoXY[]){
        this.origemXY[0] = origemXY[0];
        this.origemXY[1] = origemXY[1];
        this.destinoXY[0] = destinoXY[0];
        this.destinoXY[1] = destinoXY[1]; 
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Da minha outra classe mando as cordenadas nos vetores e a linha é desenhada, porém se mando outras coordenadas para desenhar uma outra linha, a linha anterior é apagada. Acho que o repaint faz isso de apagar o que tem e desenhar novamente, mas se tirar ele nada é desenhado. Preciso desenhar mais de uma, obrigado.

Comment: Não seria uma solução armazenar os valores obtidos no método `drawLinha(int origemXY[], int destinoXY[])` em outras variáveis? Algo do tipo `origemXYAtual` para as correntes e `origemXYAnterior` para a antiga?

Comment: Sim talvez daria, mas acho existe formas de manter o que já foi desenhado, e no meu caso eu desejaria que a cada vez chamado já desenhasse